# Send Generic type to the base class?

Tags: c#, generics

Usually this is how I have been making generic Type for class properties:

My model looks like :

```
public class CustomerProfile<T> where T : class 
{
   public T Address{ get; set; }
  }
```

Code to send type to the generic type class from my client code:

```
 var genericTypeParameter  = typeof(CustomerAddress);
 var genericBaseType = typeof(CustomerProfile);
 var genericType = genericBaseType.MakeGenericType(genericTypeParameter  );
```

Now I have to create the class hierarchy as follows:

```
  public class Customer : CustomerProfile
  {
       public Customer Names { get; set; }
   }
```

Now  how can I send the type CustomerAddress type to the CustomerProfile class Generic Type?

Comment: "*Send*" is not the best terminology to use here. I think the word you want is "*assign*"

Comment: Also Its not clear how you can create this `public class Customer : CustomerProfile` and not get a compiler error,  when your class is actually `CustomerProfile<T>`. Which makes this question a little unclear

Comment: HI General.. I am getting compile error .. I just put the code to show my intention

Comment: Are you asking how to dynamically create `class Customer : CustomerProfile<CustomerAddress>` at runtime?

Comment: Yes Jerry. Basically use my above code to generate generic type and assign to the base class.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I send the type CustomerAddress type to the CustomerProfile class Generic Type?

You simply need to specify the type in the declaration:

```cs
public class Customer : CustomerProfile<CustomerAddress>
{
    public Customer Names { get; set; }
}
```

If you don't know the `CustomerAddress` type at compile time, then you will need to make `Customer` generic:

```cs
public class Customer<T> : CustomerProfile<T>
{
    public Customer Names { get; set; }
}
```

And then get the `Customer<T>` type the same way you are currently getting `CustomerProfile<T>`.

I admit, the rest of the code you posted seems odd. It's not clear why you are using reflection to instantiate a type for which you know the type parameter at compile time. `typeof(CustomerProfile<CustomerAddress>)` should work just as well as the reflection-based code you posted.

And it seems odd to have a `Names` property having the same type as the declaring type.

But as far as getting the correct type parameter to the base class, it's trivial, per the example above.

Comment: Hi Peter: sorry to confuse you but I  actually posted a modified code. I wont be  aware of the type during compile time.

Comment: _"I wont be aware of the type during compile time"_ -- well, that's not the question you asked. Your question is _specific_ that you want to pass `CustomerAddress` as the type parameter. I will update the answer based on my best guess about what you actually mean, but if that doesn't address your question, then you need to fix your question so it's clear.

Comment: Thankyou Peter.  Basically I want use my above makegeneric type code to generate generic type and assign that to the base class CustomerProfile<T>

Comment: _"I want use my above makegeneric type code to generate generic type and assign that to the base class CustomerProfile<T>"_ -- Using the code you have, the only way to do that is to make the derived class generic as well, as I explain above. If you are willing to introduce .NET's runtime type building, you can make a new type at runtime that inherits the closed generic type. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13276447/create-type-myclass-otherclassmyclass-at-runtime. Of course, with that technique, you will have _no_ compile-time access to the derived type.